# What is the simplest way to offer/consume web services in jython?

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, jython

I have an application for Tomcat which needs to offer/consume web services. Since Java web services are a nightmare (xml, code generation, etc.) compared with what is possible in Python, I would like to learn from your experience using jython instead of java for offerring/consuming web services.

What I have done so far involves adapting http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/ to [Jython](http://www.jython.org). I still get errors (namespaces, types and so), although some of it is succesful for the simplest services.

Comment: I should have said what interests me the most is SOAP/WSDL type of thing. I am trying to be buzzword-compliant :-)

Answer (score 2):

I've put together more details on how to use webservices in jython using axis.  Read about it here: [How To Script Webservices with Jython and Axis](http://www.fishandcross.com/blog/?p=503).

Answer (score 0):

[PyServlet](http://www.jython.org/docs/api/org/python/util/PyServlet.html) helps you configure Tomcat to serve up Jython scripts from a URL.  You could use this is a "REST-like" way to do some basic web services without much effort.  (It is also described [here](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=26865&seqNum=6).)

We used a similar home grown framework to provide a variety of data services in a large multiple web application very successfully.